# Android: Problems Referencing Header File

Tags: android, c

I am trying to compile the Doom Code found [Here](http://www.apress.com/9781430247975). However when I run ndk-build I see the following...

```
jni/droid/i_video.c:45:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

but...

```
find ./ -name SDL.h
.//SDL-1.2.13/include/SDL.h
```

And my Android.mk shows...

```
DOOM := apps/Doom/project/jni
INC             := -I$(DOOM) -I$(DOOM)/include -I$(DOOM)/SDL-1.2.13/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := $(DOOM_FLAGS) $(OPTS) $(INC)
```

Anyone able to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to put all of the include in the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable instead of the `INC` variable as `INC` is unused by the android-ndk build system.

This Changes your line to (Note the removed `-I`)

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(DOOM) $(DOOM)/include $(DOOM)/SDL-1.2.13/include
```

Below is  quoted the relevant section for LOCAL_C_INCLUDES

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES
    An optional list of paths, relative to the NDK *root* directory,
    which will be appended to the include search path when compiling
    all sources (C, C++ and Assembly). For example:

        LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := sources/foo

    Or even:

        LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../foo

    These are placed before any corresponding inclusion flag in
    LOCAL_CFLAGS / LOCAL_CPPFLAGS

    The LOCAL_C_INCLUDES path are also used automatically when
    launching native debugging with ndk-gdb.
```

Comment: Sorry should have included more code, I will update... Updated... so I am already technically doing this correct?

Comment: @Jackie it looks right to me. Can you show the path of where you are running `ndk-build` and are you sure `apps/Doom/project/jni` is a relative directory from where you are running `ndk-build`